Why do people keep saying that "rate" is the number of something that happens over a period of time?
I have raised some questions about how "rate" should be used in our forum, and most of the time, people just left the discussion when I still had a lot of questions in my head.

"Rate" is the number of something that happens during a particular period.

This is not only what people told me, but it is also what I found in the dictionary. When I asked if a phrase like the rate of contingent workers per 1000 population was correct, many told me that it was not because of either of these problems:

(1) It must be something that happens
(2) "per 1000 population" is awkward.

Here's my question for each problem:

(1) What about poverty rate, which is the proportion of people living below the poverty line to the toal population of a country? It's not the measurement of those who become poor, it's the measurement of those who are poor. There's nothing happening here. The same question for unemployment rate, and I can name so many more examples like these.


(2) See this table which shows data on the crime rates of different cities in the US. The title is: Yearly Crime Rates per 100,000 people. So why is it okay but "the rate of contingent workers per 1000 population" is incorrect?

I hope you can help me work it out this time. Thanks a lot!

"flow rate" of water, for example, is measured in units like "gallons per minute".  But things like "unemployment rate" are simple ratios, e.g. thefts involving handguns per 100,000 citizens might be the "aggravated robbery" rate.

You said people "leave the discussion" - but this isn't a discussion forum; it is a question-and-answer site. I've answered all 3 of your questions today on rates. I'm the principal data analyst for a large organisation with a team of senior analysts working under me; the only analyst senior to me is a data scientist. I'm starting to think that your questions are straying beyond English grammar and into a technical area that is off-topic. I really hope my answer to this question satisfies you because it isn't good form to ask new question when you don't believe the answer to a previous one.

You'd usually apply rate to phenomena or events, but not to things or people - "unemployment rate" or "car accident rate" works, but "*the rate of unemployed" or "*car rate" doesn't.

It is the raw number per 100,000 that expresses the rate.  So you wouldn't say "the rate per 100,000"  (though most people wouldn't balk at that).   Unemployment rate was 5,000 per 100,000 or 5%.

@Astralbee There seems to be a misunderstanding here. I believe you might not have noticed the time when I created this post. I did it immediately after my three comments on your answer in the other post, BEFORE you replied to those comments. It's not that I didn't believe you because (1) I hadn't even read your responses, and (2) we seem to be in agreement here, aren't we? I posted this question right afterwards simply because I had another point to make and wanted people to discuss it more.

And when I said "people just leave the discussion", I wasn't talking about you. The first questions I posted here related to "rate" were weeks ago. You are actually the most passionate person who replied to this topic so far, so I'm grateful for that.

@TimR I see where you're coming from. But what about "crime rates per 100,000 people"? It seems that people do use "rates per X population".

@MaciejStachowski So you mean "unemployment", "literacy", ... are phenomena, but "contingent workers" are not and that's the problem right? I think it's an interesting point even though it's a bit hard for me to decide which is defined a phenomenon. Could everybody else share your thoughts on this?

@KenAdams "some people" is a very low bar.  raw number/100k people is a unit of measure used when expressing such rates for the entire population. It's  a convenient way to keep the raw number manageably small and to allow comparison of one population to another when the populations are of different sizes and so looking at the raw numbers alone would be relatively meaningless. It will always be the rate  for the entire population expressed as a ratio of raw number per 100,000. Or sometimes per 1000. The denominator number can vary and would be given in a "key".

I'm not sure if I have fully grasped what you are saying. As far as I understand, you mean we can't use "the rate per X population is Y", but we can still say "the rate of contingent workers is 5,000 per 100,000 population", just like we can say "unemployment rate is 5,000 per 100,000". Do I understand it correctly?

@KenAdams In response to your last comment - I say you are fine to express any number compared to the whole population as a "rate", so that would include both your examples. I think the whole confusion in all of your posts comes down to the erroneous use of the word "ratio".

Think about it: You can't measure a rate except over a time period. "the rate of contingent workers is 5,000 per 100,000 population"=no. BUT: the rate of contingent workers fired in the last month was 5,000 per 100,000 population=Yes. A rate is always in terms of something,and over time.

The word "rate" simply means one number divided by another, a ratio. Like, thefeedictionary.com defines "rate" as "A quantity measured with respect to another measured quantity".
OFTEN the denominator of the fraction is time. Like we talk about "rate of growth", the amount of increase per unit time, or "rate of speed", the distance you travel per unit time. But a rate doesn't ALWAYS involve time. Like we talk about the "tax rate", the amount of tax divided by your total income. Or the "crime rate", the number of crimes divided by the total population.
(If you tried to ask this before and someone wouldn't give you a straight answer or gave you an incorrect answer ... sorry. Wasn't me. :-)

I don't know why people say that because it's not true. Rates don't need to involve time.
The term "rate" is typically used to describe the number of occurrences of an event or phenomenon within a specific population and/or over a specified period. For example, "the crime rate per 1,000 people". But it isn't time dependant because it can be used in connection with census data (ie a 'snapshot' of time rather than a measured period of time).
I would imagine the reason think a rate must imply something happening over time is because the purpose of calculating a rate is to suggest that rate would apply to any given sample of the same size. For example, to calculate that a vehicle is traveling at 30 miles per hour there is no requirement for the car to travel a mile or for an hour. You could travel for half an hour at 30mph and travel 15 miles, or drive a mile in 2 minutes. The speed (rate) is calculated on available data using a numerator and a denominator and the inference is that, in any hour travelling at that speed, you would cover 30 miles.
Perhaps 'occurs' would be a better word than 'happens' for your quotation. The rate of something doesn't have be timestamped occurrences - it can just be the number of people or things that you would find within a dataset. For example, the word count in a book of a specific word could be described both as the number of times that word "occurs", and the number expressed as a percentage or some other comparison against the total word count could be referred to as the rate at which it occurs.

A crime rate per 1,000 people has to involve time. Otherwise, they all committed a crime on the same date? Doesn't it always involve dates? And with miles per hour, doesn't that by definition involve time? However, a tax rate doesn't involve time, as Jay pointed out...

@lambie Speaking of time, I don't post for a couple of days so you have to find a post from 6 months ago to criticise? Wow. Well, you're wrong, of course. When we talk about 'time' in the context of statistics we are talking about time series. A time series is something like miles per hour or sales per month. But not everything with a time or date is a time series. Populations change every day - perhaps even every second - as people are born, die, move house etc. But most population figures come from some kind of census or head count which occur annually or even every ten years.

I am just asking about what don't get in your answer. I happened upon it, I did not go looking for it. But excuse me, after reading about this I see that if you take data points at specific moments in time and put them on a chart, each one individually is not dependent on time, it's a static shot in time, right? but to show a trend, there's time.

@Lambie Yes, that's right. And to be fair, you can show a trend in something like a crime rate falling or rising year on year. But if the rate is crimes per capita then the numerator is a count of crimes committed in a calendar year and that is adjusted by a snapshot of the population which may well be for the previous year, or any time in the last 10 years if it is the decennial census. The rate itself doesn't involve time, and the direct answer to the OP's question is no - a rate doesn't necessarily mean over time.

I don't think it has to be something that happens. Instead, I would say that rate reflects an amount that varies based on what it is describing. For example:
unemployment rate - amount of unemployment
poverty rate - amount of poverty
crime rate - amount of crime

An  unemployment rate is a percentage, so how can that be an amount, on the face of it?
